CSS Custom Properties with fallback for unrecognised css value (eg. clamp())
As it stands, CSS Custom Properties enjoys a global tracked base of 99.05% support according to CanIUse. Most of this is due to IE support that has one of a number off poly fills particularly when said variables are based in :root.
However, the limitations of browser compatibility with newer css declarations does not end here. What is the effect of an unrecognised value on a css custom property when custom properties are supported but the value is not.
:root {
  --fun-size: 12px;
  --fun-size: clamp(0.75rem, 0.5rem + 1vw, 1.25rem);
}

Now:
.test-use-of-fun-size {
  font-size: var(--fun-size);
}

If custom properties are not supported clearly font-size will act as if it has not received a value and default to whatever it has currently inherited. What if, custom properties are supported but clamp is not supported. Did it receive 12px or did it receive an invalid value.
Context, I am trying to migrate away from an ever exploding load of SASS that fixes all of this but the scalability of the library I wrote to interpolate it all requires remembering so many variables constantly that every time a new exploit comes along it's a pain if the whole thing could just be written simply.

Try some experiments - I didn’t get what I expected if the variable is defined within the style attribute for example.

I get different results by different browsers and versions of said browsers. I'm trying to establish if there is a constant here and therefore if this can be used reasonably safely. From what I can see, it can't and that would somewhat explain why there is no documentation on it even in the official spec. Did no one think of this?

Sorry to persist but I don't think you're really getting my point. There is a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/9jnm6fdy/. The problem is that this fiddle gives no way to test the effect on a browser that does not support clamp(). Will it default to 12px (ie. referencing the last understood value of --fun-size or will it in fact give an invalid value thus relying on whatever .test-use-of-fun-size can inherit.

Quite so, what I found with a simple test on Chrome/W10 was that giving a rubbish value for a variable and then assigning it to font-size in the style attribute overrode any setting in a stylesheet (and the value seemed to go back to initial) whereas if I did it all in the style attribute it took the OK value. So my conclusion is that there is no standard laid down for this, or if there is Chrome gives different results so you can't rely on anything. Not sure what the workaround could be. Hope someone on here knows more about any standard relating to this.

Tis what I thought. Thanks for having a look. I was hoping there was a standard on this but it seems every declaration of value will still need the property set twice. At least css is coming along. Best,

If you want automatic fallbacks for things like font-size: clamp(...) a postCSS step might be a good solution here.

To test such a thing, consider a random function to see what is happening:


:root {
  --fun-size: 45px;
  --fun-size: random_function(0.75rem, 0.5rem + 1vw, 1.25rem);
}

body {
  font-size: var(--fun-size);
}
some text content



As you can see the 45px will not be used and the second value (even if it's clearly invalid) will always be used.
From the Specification:

If a property contains one or more var() functions, and those functions are syntactically valid, the entire property’s grammar must be assumed to be valid at parse time. It is only syntax-checked at computed-value time, after var() functions have been substituted. ref

Then

A declaration can be invalid at computed-value time if it contains a var() that references a custom property with the guaranteed-invalid value, as explained above, or if it uses a valid custom property, but the property value, after substituting its var() functions, is invalid. ref


Thanks. So fundamentally there must still be two css properties set for say font-size (one likely valid: 12px, and one possibly invalid var(--fun-size) every time this is used in a css class. Annoying but I suppose consistently annoying.

@Walrus no, it won't work that way as well. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/pax8rmsL/ .. the font-size: var() is still considered because it's only invalid at computed-value time so if you use something invalid inside a CSS variable it's dead for you. There is no way to use something else instead.

That's a bit more of a spanner in the works than I was expecting. So the value of a custom property will be assumed to be valid even if it isn't when used in class. But if we perform whatever that value is on a css class itself and it is invalid it will default to what has previously been declared or inherited. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dj8ouxnL/2/. Therefore I propose that the values are stored in scss and added in order assuming this analysis in the fiddle is correct.

@Tamani Atif : more sensible fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dj8ouxnL/3/
